# Where is recommended spot for storing admin customizations for Django contrib apps?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add Django Sessions to my Django Admin, and I am following an [SO post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976015/django-how-to-see-session-data-in-the-admin-interface), but it is unclear where I store this code. Do I put it in an admin.py file? Under what directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it doesn't matter. You can put the code into any of your apps' admin.py files. However, in situations like these I tend to use a generic app in my project, usually named something like `utils`, that exists for the sole purpose of housing code that doesn't belong to one specific app or could be used by multiple apps.

If you want to be more specific, you can create a `sessions` app in your project specifically devoted to this code and any other code related to session management for your project, or perhaps an existing app that is somewhat related. For example, I put customizations to the `User` admin in my `accounts` app that holds the `UserProfile` model.